# VBA Runs in Debug mode, but fails in Production

Tags: excel, vba

My code is working perfectly in debug mode.  I step through every single line, and it outputs exactly how I expect.  However, when it runs on open, like i want it to, it doesn't execute the last 2-3 lines properly.  I put a note where it stops in the code snip below.  I am a very amateur coder, so please forgive the toddler level organization and efficiency.  Any and all critiques or suggestions are welcome, I am really just figuring this out as i go.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Message asks user if they want to update
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
Answer = MsgBox("Would you like to update the part HS database for your tracker?" & vbCrLf & "(It will take a hot minute)", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Update Part DB")


'if check for running the subroutine

If Answer = vbYes Then


    ''Turn off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


        'Open parser
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="K:\04_Classification\Broker Templates\BrokerPartsListParser.xlsb", ReadOnly:=True

        'Setting Range Variables
        Dim RgData As Range
        Dim RgCriteria As Range
        Dim RgOutput As Range
        Set RgData = Workbooks("BrokerPartsListParser.xlsb").Worksheets("NewestIPExtract").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set RgCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PartDBRef").Range("J1").CurrentRegion
        Set RgOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PartDBRef").Range("A3").CurrentRegion

        'Clearing previous data
        RgOutput.Offset(1).ClearContents

        'Doing the Advanced Filter
        RgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, RgCriteria, RgOutput







        'Check to see if ACE data needs to be pulled

        Dim ACEPull As Boolean: ACEPull = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AO2")

        If ACEPull = True Then

            'setting pulled date
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AK2").Value = Date

            'Finding last row of old data set
            Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


            'Deleting old Data
            If IsEmpty(Range("AA2").Value) = False Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("A2:AA" & LastRow).ClearContents
            End If


            'Setting Advanced Filter Parameters
            Set RgData = Workbooks("BrokerPartsListParser.xlsb").Worksheets("Unified ACE Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Set RgCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AH1").CurrentRegion
            Set RgOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("A1:AA1")


            'Doing the Advanced Filter
            RgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, RgCriteria, RgOutput


''THIS IS WHERE MY CODE STOPS WORKING AS I WOULD EXPECT

            'Finding New Last Row
            LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            'Filling Formulas
            If IsEmpty(Range("AA3").Value) = False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AB2:AD" & LastRow).FillDown
            End If


        End If




        ''close parser
        Workbooks("BrokerPartsListParser.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False




    ''Turn updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ''Thank people for their patience
    MsgBox "Part DB has been updated.  Thank you for your patience :D"

    Exit Sub
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You got an implicit range reference. `IsEmpty(Range("AA3").Value)`not saying this is your culprit, but it could well be. I haven't been through the rest of your code.

Comment: @JvdV That totally fixed my problem! Thank you so much.  Why on earth would that not  be a problem in debug and be an issue when the script runs all at once?

Comment: That's because implicit reference means it is referencing the then active worksheet. When in debug you might have the right sheet activated. However, during run-time it's probably not.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate JvdV's comment you have an implicit range reference.Try adding the workbook and worksheet referenced to the IsEmpty statement.

```
 'Filling Formulas
            If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AA3").Value) = False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ACE Data").Range("AB2:AD" & LastRow).FillDown
            End If

``
```

Comment: Thanks Rose!! that did it :)